# Is this normal behavior for mysql_real_escape_string?

Tags: php, mysql

I just disabled magic_quotes_gpc and I notice that the user input into my database has apostrophes as if nothing was escaped.

```
($_POST['message'])="it's a test";
$string = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['message']));
```

Then I insert it into the database and the database shows: 
`it's a test`

Isn't it supposed to be `it\'s a test`, after I applied `mysql_real_escape_string`?
Or is it the database (here, with PHPMyAdmin) that translates those `\'` into `'`?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @deceze: he said, database with phpmyadmin. He's correct in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of escaping SQL is to avoid SQL innjection. `INSERT INTO table VALUES ('it's a test') ..` would cause you trouble, but when you escape it it turns to `INSERT INTO table VALUES ('it\'s a test') ..` and that will work and insert "'it's a test'" to your database.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Just needed confirmation because was used to seeing those backslashes in my database, with those dreaded magic_quotes. Regards

Answer (score 1):

mysql_real_escape_string() just escapes characters to correctly put them to DB. So you wouldn't see no backslashes in yur DB.

Due to mysql Doc(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences):

```
That is, the escaped character is interpreted as if it was not escaped. For example, “\x” is just “x”.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your link. I was actually looking up on php.net but couldn't find that confirmation there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When `INSERT INTO atable VALUES ('it\'s a test')` query execute

Only `"it's a test"` store in your database :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. But when I want to SELECT that string from the database and display it, is it normal that it's displayed as `it\'s a test`? Thanks